# can we manually make input valid in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input attached with datepicker. when  click datepicker, date will be entered into the input. But the input remained as invalid(i have 'required' condition on input) as i did not enter anything manually. i could not submit form because of this. can we programatically make the input valid

```
    <body ng-controller="ReservationController as resvnCtrl">
        <form role="form" name="resvnCtrl.form" data-ng-submit="resvnCtrl.submitForm(resvnCtrl.form.$valid)" novalidate>

          <div class="form-group" data-ng-class="{'has-error':resvnCtrl.form.time.$invalid && (resvnCtrl.form.time.$dirty || resvnCtrl.form.$submitted) }">
              <label class="control-label">Date & Time</label>
              <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>
                  <input type="text" name="time" id="time" data-ng-model="resvnCtrl.user.time"
                         placeholder="Enter Desired Time" class="form-control" required>
                  <span class="input-group-addon pointer"  data-date-picker>
                      <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                  </span>
              </div>
              <div data-ng-messages="resvnCtrl.form.time.$error" data-ng-if="resvnCtrl.form.time.$dirty || resvnCtrl.form.$submitted">
                  <p class="help-block" data-ng-message="required">Date & Time required</p>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
                  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Make Reservation" class="btn btn-primary btn-block " >
              </div>
          </div>       

       </form>
      </body>
```

here is the plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/1l167VHFg32IkvEaDFgf?p=preview

Comment: Why don't you remove the "required" attribute if the field is not required?

Comment: It is required. so using it